PluginInterface and Entity Framework
I have the following projects:

MyApp.DAL (Contains the dbcontext)
MyApp.PluginInterface (Contains interfaces that the plugin projects can implement)

I make dll out of it by publishing. Then I add two plugin project:

Plugin.A
Plugin.B

Plugin.A has the model of Person.
Plugin.B has the model of House.
I would like to use Person in Plugin.B in order to add habitants to the house.
BUT I do not have the option to reference Project.A.
How can I do this with entity framework?\
Why you might ask?
Since I do not want to reinvent the wheel by implementing the kind of stuff like Where,Select,OrderBy and so on...  that EF has out of the box.
Currently I am using ADO.NET to access data from anywhere via strings.\n
That constructs the sql command to acces the data.
An example:
From(DataTableReference.Standard("TestTable")).Join("col4", DataTableReference.Standard("NumbersTable"), "num");

Person should not be in Plugin.A, rather in MyApp.PluginInterface or some other shared project.  The concrete "models" (if any), not just the "plugins", should derive from shared abstract definitions.

P.S.  Or, if just a set of concrete models is enough, simply have a "models" project that is shared.

Okay, I will try it out, and get back with the results. Thank U @JulioDiEgidio !
